# Session not storing some values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I'm not a C# programmer anymore (last project in 2005), but I fell on a ASP.NET 4.0 project and to made some "small" changes.

I'm not really sure HOW can I look/search about this problem, but, here we go:

When I'm on a controller, and I set a session with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = "mydata";` and I'm trying to retrieve in the view with this:

```
@{
    String test = "";
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] != null) {
        test = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"];
    }
}

--<span>@test</span>--
```

But the session is always null.

The problem is if I test with another session key ("MEX.User" for instance) already used in the system, it works.

I don't know where is the big deal, and neither how to find it.

---

### Update

I ran the project in another Windows 7 machine and the sessions worked fine. Now I have to figure out why it's not working on stating and development environments. Staging is exactly like production, so I think it will not work either.

Comment: First of all, it's not necessary to say `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` in your view...you can just say `Session`.

Comment: I know, but I put it to ensure that I'm not getting Session from the wrong namespace. It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I think this is an issue with order of execution.
Are you 100% sure you're setting the session in the correct action method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, since I can set another value to an existing session without problem, but session with unused keys doesn't work.

Comment: Now I figured out that is an environment problem, because it worked in another machine.

Comment: this might seem a little basic. but you can try clearing the cache of the machine?

Comment: client side cache has nothing at all to do with a server side cache. In the order of events of setting a session in the same request, the client makes zero differnece. if it sends a sessionid over, the server uses it, otherwise a new one is assigned during that request to be sent to the client at the end of the request.  Rafael, is there a root web.config that has sessionstate disabled in an application in a folder above your app? Which web server?

Comment: keshav: Which cache? How I clean it?

Comment: Adam Tuliper: My web.config only have `<compilation debug="true">`. I'm using IIS 7.5 (Windows 7)